# android.support.v7.widget.CardView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class) Using Android Studio 3.4

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-cardview

I've been building an app and it's been working well until I updated to the latest Android Studio. I've been getting the error
" android.support.v7.widget.CardView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)"
My cardview doesn't show the image.
The app compiles well and installs to my phone but crashes on start up. And it was working fine yesterday. I have the lastest dependencies and I don't know why my cardviewer isn't working. Any solution? Do I need to downgrade the sdkversion? I've looked everywhere and followed a lot of fixes and now I'm literally pulling my hair off trying to get this one error to be fixed. Changing the currently dependencies to match the buildToolsVersion doesn't seem to work either.

[A picture of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGgJy.png)

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Suicune">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="12">


    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnCount="1"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:rowCount="3">

        <!-- Row 1 -->

        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/suicuneframedata_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/framedata_button" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/suicunecombosheets_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/combosheets_button" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/suicunenotableplayers_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/notableplayers_button" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java Class

```
package com.example.sayafkadam.ptdxassault;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

 public class Suicune extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_suicune);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Suicune Database");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    ImageView FrameData;
    ImageView ComboSheets;
    ImageView NotablePlayers;


    FrameData = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.suicuneframedata_button);
    FrameData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intentLoadSuicuneInfo = new Intent(Suicune.this,           
    SuicuneFD.class);
            startActivity(intentLoadSuicuneInfo);
        }
    });


    NotablePlayers = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.suicunenotableplayers_button);
    NotablePlayers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intentLoadNotablePlayers = new Intent(Suicune.this, 
 SuicuneNP.class);
            startActivity(intentLoadNotablePlayers);
        }
    });
 }
 }
```

My Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sayafkadam.ptdxassault"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
 buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
 }

  dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.1.0-beta.1'
implementation 'gr.pantrif:easy-android-splash-screen:0.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using

```
 implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

Instead and

```
androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
```

In XML?

Comment: That did it! I very much appreciate the help. I have to do this for about 30+ XML files now. Can you explain why this wasn't working before? Is it because I have to use androidx?

Comment: @Nobel Yea I'm guessing it's just not supported now since the support library has been replaced by the androidx library more or less. Might want to replace the rest of your libraries with androidx as well

Comment: @Nobel on a second note to easily replace all of them at once do ctrl+shift+r and just do a bulk text replacement